# Remove a Div Class from one element in HTML

Tags: html, css

There's a css class called `.main-container` and I just have repeat that div class several times in the document. What I just want is to remove the very first container. Can I do with that child class ?

Comment: can't you just delete class="main-controller" from the div you want to delete it from?

Comment: Can you add some markup and be a bit more specific? I'm not exactly sure about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i cant delete the main-container because i've used that several times , 

<body>
<div class="main-container">
content-1
</div>

<div class="main-container">
content-2
</div>

<div class="main-container">
content-3
</div>

so likewise i just need to remove the main-container only from CSS , without removing it from the html document .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var removeEl=document.getElementsByClassName('main-container')[0];
removeEl.parentElement.removeChild(removeEl);
```

It is a clean, working solution without jQuery.

Comment: is there anyway that i can do the same thing using CSS only ?

Comment: can i just do it when the max-width gone down then do the above thing

Comment: You cannot access the first occurrence of the class using CSS. It would work with a tag name like this: div:nth-child(1) { display: none; }

Comment: You could check for the max-width in an interval and trigger the above function if it was reached.

Answer (score 0):

there are a jquery function eq(index), that you put your index as parameter on it.

**this is the script what you need:**

```
$(".main-container").eq(0).removeClass(".main-container");
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
$('.main-container').first().remove();
```

or

```
$('.main-container span:first').remove();
```

if you want to remove class then use reomveclass() instead remove()

Answer (score 0):

For accomplish this task you should use Jquery/Javascript. You can not able to achieve `remove class` thing only using HTML/CSS.

Use jquery [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) selector:

```
$('.main-container').first().removeClass('main-container');
```

OR

```
$('.main-container:first').removeClass('main-container');
```

OR if you want : the Css style is not append/added/apply on the first container with `main-container` class, then you can use css `not` selector:

```
.main-container:not(:first-child)
{
   //-- Your Style
}
```